# pipenv/pip install from git commit/revision id

Tags: pip, dependencies, pipenv, python-packaging, pipfile

I would like to install a package from a git repository specifying a commit id using pipenv (I belive it should be very similar If I would use pip)

so far I tried:

`pipenv install "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repository>.git/<commit_id>#egg=mypackage"`

which is apending the following line to the Pipfile & provides no errors

`<package-name> = {git = "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repository>.git/<commit_id>"}`

If I import the package `import mypackage` it detects it but its dependencies are missing.

The setup.py of **mypackage** looks like;

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as readme:
    long_description = readme.read()
with open("./requirements.txt", "r") as fh:
requirements = fh.readlines()

setuptools.setup(
    name='mypackage',
    url='https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<repositroy>',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    install_requires=[req for req in requirements if req[0] not in ["#", "-"]],
```

)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just figured it out by reading [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#git) that the revision id should be specified after a @

`pipenv install  "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repository>.git@<commit_id>#egg=<package_name>"`

Comment: important note: it looks like all parts *must* be presented, including <commit_id> and egg=<package_name>